# How to set elements relative to div

Tags: html, css

I'm learning HTML/CSS and I'm having a little trouble finding a way to set elements relative to a container.

I've read up on the difference between "relative" and "absolute" positioning.  "relative" positioning, positions the element relative to where the default position should be.  However is there a way to position elements relative to a container (in this case, the orange box?)

For example, is there a way to position all the text and img's inside the orange box, so whenever i decide to move the orange box around, all the elements inside will stay put?

HTML:

```
        <div class="container">


        <div id="snappyText">
            <p>Ever think,"Where are the most mediocre places to eat around here? I want me some of that."</p>
        </div>
        <div id="response">
            <p>-Yeah, neither do we.</p>
        </div><!--end Snappy Text-->

        <div id="iphonePic">
            <img src="images/iphone.png" alt="phone" />
        </div><!--end iphonePic-->

        <div id="dashVideo">
            <img src="images/videoThumbnail.png" alt="video" />
        </div><!--end dashVideo-->

        <div id="appStoreIcon">
            <img src="images/appstore.png" alt="appstore" />
            <!--<img src="images/free.png" alt="free" />-->
        </div><!--end appStoreIcon-->

        <div id="explanatoryText">
            <p>Dash is the quickest way to find good places to eat. In a world with too many choices and too much information, Dash clears the clutter and offers only the best in your area.</p>  
        </div><!--end explanatoryText-->

        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://boxoutdev.com/">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="socialMedia">
            <a href="http://twitter.com/#!/thedashapp"><img src="images/twitter.png" alt="twitter" /></a>

            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/"><img src="images/facebook.png" alt="facebook" /></a>
        </div><!--end socialMedia-->

    </div><!--end container-->
```

CSS:

```
#logo{
display:block;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
position:relative;
top:40px;
}
#main .container{
background-image: url(images/orangeBackground.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
top:90px;
}

/*orange box*/

#snappyText{
color:white;
font-size:30px;
font-family:Helvetica;
font-weight:lighter;
padding-top:30px;
padding-left:50px;
padding-right:50px;
line-height:30px;

}

#response{
color:white;
font-size:40px;
font-family:Helvetica;
font-weight:lighter;
padding-left:260px;
padding-right:50px;
padding-top:50px;

}

#iphonePic{
position:relative;
left:64px;
bottom:-50px;
}

#dashVideo{
position:relative;
left:350px;
top:-460px;
}

#appStoreIcon{
position:relative;
left:350px;
top:-420px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use absolute positioning, all those elements inside the box will stay positioned relative to the containing box since you set that containing box to 'position:relative'. For that matter, you can have them positioned relative inside the container, too.

Comment: I've added some of my code.  if i set the position to absolute, wont the elements just be positioned relative to the browser window?

Comment: @anc1revv - Absolutely positioned elements are placed relative to the nearest positioned element. If the parent container is position:relative, then any absolutely positioned elements inside it will follow it where you put it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You just have to set the position of the orange box to relative (or absolute) and you can position the elements in the box relative to the box corners.

Answer (score 0):

By using position:absolute - that div/object's x and y will be at the parent div/object who has a position. And the all div/objects inside that div with a position:absolute will have an x and y on their parent div.

Example

```
<div id="a">
    <div id="b">
    </div>
</div>
```

If #a has an position:absolute and you use position:absolute too on #b, #b's x and y will be at the #a's top and left corner (that's why we have top/bottom and left/right, right? <-- Lol

By using position:relative - that div/object's x and y will be the same as that div/object.

I suggest you put position:relative (w/o top/bottom & left/right to stay put) to the #container and position:relative or position:absolute inside #container so you can easily position them where ever you want